# Is there a word that can be used for both the original thing and a copy of it?

Tags: word-request

I'm writing computer program.
I have two type of objects: originals and their clones.
I need somehow describe these objects by type.
How I can call this property more concrete than just "type of object".
Maybe something like "origin type" or another variant?

I don't need word that would be specific for computer programming. There are two words "original" - something genuine, and "clone" - copy made from original. How we can describe both?

Comment: Computer programming has its own jargon that doesn't necessarily follow English dictionary definitions. I think this question is off-topic here and you'd be better asking on a programming site.

Comment: I don't need word that would be specific for computer programming. There are two words "original" - something genuine, and "clone" - copy made from original. How we can describe both?

Comment: Forget "clone". What you have is the "original" and a "copy", regardless of whether it's a data structure / "object" in a computer program, or a (forged?) banknote, painting, etc. In ordinary English, "clones" are *biological* copies.

Comment: I tried to update your title to make it clearer for people who aren't programmers what you might be asking for... If that isn't really what you were asking, please edit it. I assumed you are asking for a word to group your original thing and a copy of it together as one type of thing?

Answer (score 3):

Original and clone could be source and destination, but in computer terms the distinctions collapse quickly.

To recover your clone back to the original the two terms are reversed. I've heard this called re-cloning, though that's not an idea I'm keen on.
Also, once you have two identical versions, strictly they're both clones.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here, but I'm assuming this is the name of the attribute on either of these objects. And the attribute is either "original" or "copy". The name for this could be something like "lineage" or "lineage status"

Answer (score 0):

May be:

> Instances of the object.

And terms like: original instance(s), and derived instances.